# Trying to Install and run ipfs on elementary os

Tags: software-installation

I have tried to install [ipfs](https://ipfs.io/docs/install/) using their instructions. Yet I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Could anyone help me with this,

Thanks,

Sampath :):)

Comment: assuming that this is still not resolved ... I am running loki and followed the directions on the web site ......... seems to test out fine ......... you DID do "sudo ./install.sh" where you un-tarred the file ...didn't you ... and you did download the correct architecture?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try via a Snap package:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install ipfs
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now it works on older linuxes only.  Arch, Wheezy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using their snap package.
A non command-line way of doing that would be to:

1. Install [Snaptastic](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.bartzaalberg.snaptastic.desktop) from the AppCenter
2. Visit: https://snapcraft.io/ipfs
3. Click Install
4. Install snap package using Snaptastic.